# What happened to Huan the Wolfhound after he died?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, valar

I just finished reading the chapter of *The Silmarillion* devoted to Beren and Lúthien, which contains the greatest character in all of Tolkien's work, in my opinion:  Huan, the Wolfhound of the Valar.  He catches arrows midflight; kills countless werewolves; beats the living snot out of Sauron; scares Morgoth silly; turns on his former master when said master attempts to do evil; lets Lúthien ride him like a horse; dresses himself in a werewolf's hide to travel incognito; talks, but not so often that it gets annoying; never sleeps; and so on.

[image]
<sub>Huan and Sauron</sub>

Sadly, he sacrifices himself to save the people he loves, and as a misanthrope who adores dogs more than anything else in the world, I need to know what happened to him afterwards.

Did Huan go to the Undying Lands, or even get reincarnated on Arda to hang out with Beren and Lúthien some more?

[image]
<sub>Beren, Lúthien, and Huan ([source](http://steamey.deviantart.com/art/Beren-Luthien-and-Huan-350251708))</sub>

Comment: I don't think this is known, but it seems likely: Huan was a hound of Oromë, and immortal in a similar way to how the Elves are immortal (he left Aman with Celegorm in the Flight of the Noldor some 500 years earlier)

Comment: ***"Huan in that hour slew Carcharoth; but there in the woven woods of Doriath his own doom long spoken was fulfilled, and he was wounded mortally, and the venom of Morgoth entered into him. Then he came, and falling beside Beren spoke for the third time with words; and he bade Beren farewell before he died. Beren spoke not, but laid his hand upon the head of the hound, and so they parted."***. He died. There's no special indication (to my knowledge) that he was reborn.

Comment: @JasonBaker - I don't know how to interpret [this](http://valarguild.org/varda/Tolkien/encyc/articles/h/Huan/HuanI.htm) (look at #3 at the bottom of the page) - I don't know what the Nauglafring or whatever is, and I don't know if this note would be considered canon, and I don't have the book in question, but you could probably turn it into a great answer.

Comment: @Richard - see the link in my comment to Jason.  Even without this information, it seems extremely likely that, as a servant of the Valar, he wouldn't just die and stay dead.  He's too awesome for that.

Comment: Even though I don't share your enthusiasm about Huan, I enjoy your question because you concisely describe your motivation and why you personally are so interested in Huan.

Comment: @b_jonas - I think I was especially smitten with Huan because he reminded me of the classic Gaelic epic of *Cú Chulainn*, although I don't think Tolkien took direct inspiration from that story.

Comment: The answer depends whether Huan was 'just a dog' empowered by the Valar, or a 'spirit' who had entered into, or taken the form of, a dog.

Comment: Although I have no canon support for this, my personal belief is that the ultimate fate of the spirits of dwarves, Men, elves, and Ainar is actually the same.  Eru has told us different statements about our fate, but not specifically *conflicting* statements.  The Ainar who came to Arda are chained here for as long as Arda exists.  The spirits of elves is also chained to Arda, and those who die before Arda's end linger passively in Mandos's halls until the end of time, but Eru has specifically not told anyone what happens to them after the end of Arda.

Comment: (cont) Men will leave Arda, but at an unspecified time, and they will participate in the second Music, which will come after Arda.  Although they don't go to Mandos's halls in particular, we don't know where they linger between their death and the second Music, and a different resting place is just a minor difference.  Dwarves believe practically the same about their own fate as we know about Men.  I believe all Children of Ilúvatar share the fate that they linger until the end of Arda, then will participate in singing the second Music and recreation of the world.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. Huan is a Maia.

> But true ‘rational’ creatures, ‘speaking peoples', are all of human / ‘humanoid’ form. Only the Valar and Maiar are intelligences that can assume forms of Arda at will. Huan and Sorontar could be Maiar — emissaries of Manwë.

(HoME X, Myths Transformed)

Following the footnote, we find:

> See p. 138. - At the bottom of the page bearing the brief text V (p. 389) my father jotted down the following, entirely unconnected with the matter of the text:
>
> Living things in Aman. As the Valar would robe themselves like the Children, many of the Maiar robed themselves like other lesser living things, as trees, flowers, beasts. (Huan.)

(HoME X, Myths Transformed)

As one of the Maiar, Huan can never truly die. So whether he went back to the Valar on his death (most likely), or won't be seen again until the End, he'll be back.

Comment: Great!  This confirms that dragons, who can also speak, are also definitely Maiar.  I wanted proof for that.

Comment: Well...I thought about adding a clause that this actually problematic in some respects. Talking creatures are not necessarily Ainur, Men, or Elves. Consider Bard's sparrow. Dragons are another reason why, though some may have been. It's really the footnote that clinches it in my opinion, and the lack of alternatives available given that footnote.

Comment: Certainly not all Ainur, Men or Elves.  Dwarves are distinct from these.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a million, and +1.  You might be interested in the last few lines on [this](http://valarguild.org/varda/Tolkien/encyc/articles/h/Huan/HuanI.htm) page.  Apparently Tolkien intended to have Huan come back to life with Beren.

Comment: The only problem is, Tolkien never got very far with the stuff his son put into Myths Transformed, and so I'm not sure if we can give a definitive answer based on this.  But it might be the best we have.

Answer (score 6):

I for one believe Huan is a Maia.

If that is true, then I believe his spirit lives on after his body has died, and is chained to Arda while Arda exists.  I cannot tell if he would ever get reincarnated.

Regardless of whether Huan really is a Maia, I definitely do not believe he would get better quickly enough to meet Beren once again.  The Silmarillion tells the story of the life of Beren until its end, and Huan meeting him again does not seem to match it.  Also, when Huan died, he spoke for one last time to say goodbye to Beren, and he spoke only in the rarest occasions, and this would not qualify if they would see each other again.

My personal reasons for thinking Huan was a Maia aren't supported by canon, and aren't really convincing, so I won't describe them here.  However, there's a word of god reference claiming he might be a Maia.  En.wikipedia [states this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Middle-earth_animals#Huan):

> Tolkien wrote he was either a beast-shaped Maia or a common animal made to speak by the Valar.

And as the source of that, gives the following reference:

- Tolkien, J. R. R. (1993), Christopher Tolkien, ed., *Morgoth's Ring*, Boston: Houghton Mifflin, "Myths Transformed" VIII, pp. 410-12, ISBN 0-395-68092-1

Comment: Although it doesn't prove anything, the narrative of the Silmarillon calls Huan a hound of *Valinor* at one point.

Comment: I always thought it would have been badass if Huan only spoke two times in spite of his allotted three. Yeah, saying goodbye to Beren was all sorts of poignant, but you know he only did it to use up that third time.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem an awful lot of Maia spirits inhabited the Great Lands, if we accept that all talking, intelligent creatures were possessed of them. On the other hand, such creatures as Huan or other talking animals could be indeed just animals that were given some ability of speech and intelligence by the Powers (Eru, Valar, or even Morgoth himself for his evil creatures). For example, the stone trolls encountered by Bilbo & Co were made by Morgoth from stone and given some ability of speech and recognition. At the end of his life, Tolkien speculated that orc originated not in corrupted elves but in animals who were transformed by Morgoth and, again, given the faculty of speech and some intelligence.

If this idea is true, then Huan died like an animal, i.e. simply ceased to exist.

Comment: Umm, Valar didn't make "puppets" - creation of dwarves and conversation of Eru and Aule strongly suggests it.

Comment: I don't think Tolkien considered Huan to be just an animal.  I found this on a fan site:  
"Where then did Huan go after death? ...in his draft of the unfinished Cantos of the Lay of Leithian, Tolkien mentions the “recall” after death of Beren and… Huan! Comment of Christopher Tolkien: “in which case my father must have intended to have Huan returned from the dead with Beren” from the halls of Mandos. In the tale of the Nauglafring Huan returned to Beren and Luthien in the land of Guilwarthon after the fall of Menegroth. Huan would have liked that"

Comment: Source: http://valarguild.org/varda/Tolkien/encyc/articles/h/Huan/HuanI.htm

Answer (score -4):

> He catches arrows midflight; kills countless werewolves; beats the living snot out of Sauron; scares Morgoth silly; turns on his former master when said master attempts to do evil; lets Lúthien ride him like a horse; dresses himself in a werewolf's hide to travel incognito; talks, but not so often that it gets annoying; never sleeps

All of the proof you need that Huan is a Maia is in the above/original description. I don't think a common animal, even one given some intelligence or ability to speak by the Valar would scare Morgoth and defeat Sauron. To me, it's clear he is Maia and I agree he is an awesome and special character. I think he shares his fate with all of the other Maia.

Comment: Could you reference that quote?

Comment: Well, the quote is *from the question*. As such, this answer is little more than speculation, and adds nothing to the existing answers.